# How retribution that is too harsh affects society?

Tags: cognitive-modeling, criminology

When a criminal law is created it is usually designed so it balances retribution among other factors to be effective.

From what I can imagine, too lenient retribution long term may contribute to the general feeling of injustice in the society and encourage lynching / self-judgement.

I was wondering, what effects on society too harsh crime retribution can have? For example using corporal punishment for something minor etc.

Is there any research that tries to model such behaviors and societal effects of such laws (both too lenient or too strict or just overall)?

Comment: If you are referring to justice within law, there are 4 types of justice in play, even in criminal law. These are distributive (determining who gets what e.g. compensation), procedural (determining how fairly people are treated), retributive (based on punishment for wrong-doing) and restorative (which tries to restore relationships to "rightness" e.g. rehabilitation and/or reformation) – see https://www.beyondintractability.org/essay/types_of_justice. What have you read about the psychology of harsh justice within the 4 types?

Comment: @ChrisRogers Thank you for that link. I didn't even know where to start looking, now I have some references and general ideas I can use to start researching some more.